# Override the CreationTimestamp/UpdateTimestamp in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

In Hibernate you can use

```
@CreationTimestamp
```

and

```
@UpdateTimestamp
```

To automatically set date fields when saving entities.

But now I have one of those entities and I want to manually set the created/updated field myself.

Can I manually set my own or will it over-ride me?

Comment: We decided that this feature in hibernate is for when you never want to customize the timestamp like i am trying to do now.

Comment: Never even in tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think the answer is - this feature in hibernate is not meant for when you want to customize the values. it is just meant for when you want strictly created/updated values during database saves.

i need to make a new column.